# Error changing compiler from JRE1.7 to OpenJdk6 : java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: family

Tags: java

I've just switched my java program to use openjdk6 from java 1.7 and now it wont compile. Can anyone help, im a long time developer but newish in Java.

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: family
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.initIDs(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.<clinit>(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:346)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openServerSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:51)
    at java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel.open(ServerSocketChannel.java:92)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:89)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:140)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:45)
```

"main" looks like

```
import app.Controller;
import quickfix.ConfigError;
import static libs.Library.log;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            log("Starting...");

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            Controller client = new Controller();
            client.login();

            synchronized (client)
            {
                try {
                    client.wait();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
        catch (ConfigError e) {
            log("Config error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any valid reasons to use OpenJDK6?

Comment: It may be due to your MySQL driver. Check its version. It may require Java 1.7.

Comment: Do a clean + build on all sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacktrace is showing that you are trying to run it from inside Intellij IDEA. Injellij IDEA doesn't guarantee that it will work on OpenJDK. A quote from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

> Using OpenJDK is not recommended, it has known visual and performance problems that affect some users. Use on your own risk if Oracle JDK has more severe issues on your system.

Try compiling and running from command line. But if you want to keep using Intellij IDEA switch to Oracle JDK.

Comment: im only accepting your answer because i have no other way to close this question than to delete it and i want to keep it as a record. I just kept with using Java JRE 1.7 so its no longer an issue.